# Switch order of attribute after creating a lot of products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute

How do you change the order of attributes, that are already in use in configurable products?

For example I have an attribute with the sizes: S, M, XL, L. These attributes have different "Position" values? And I have a lot of products using these attributes. What happens if I change XL to be L? That would mean it would loose all of these connections?

- S  : 1
- M  : 2
- XL : 3
- L  : 4

This is a simplified version of what I have. I have 12-15 different attributes, with maybe 50-200 different attribute values.

Any easy solution? Or explaination why this is not easy achievable?

Comment: `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`, select the attribute you want to change and click on the tab `Manage Label / Options`, there you should find an option called **Position**, which you can set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`, select the attribute you want to change and click on the tab `Manage Label / Options`.

There you can change the **position** value of each label / option of your attribute. This will change the entire store.

A good idea here is to have some "space" between the numbers in case you need to add more options. For example, instead of having:

- Option S - Position 1
- Option M - Position 2
- Option L - Position 3

You can use:

- Option S - Position 5
- Option M - Position 10
- Option L - Position 15

In this last case, if you need to add an option between S and M, you don't need to change all position numbers, you could just add the new option in position 7.